# Matlab emxArray_real_t Assignment in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, matlab-coder

I've Converted Some Matlab Code to C++ using Matlab Coder Tools.
I have declared 2 arrays like This:

```
   emxArray_real_T *overflowIF
   emxArray_real_T *overflowIFTemp
   overflowIF = emxCreateWrapper_real_T(NULL,0,0)
   overflowIFTemp = emxCreateWrapper_real_T(NUll,0,0)
```

where overflowIFTemp is The output of Matlab Function and just after the function call i do sth like this:

```
   overflowIF = overflowIFTemp
```

or even:

```
   *overflowIF=  *overflowIFTemp
```

at this point there is no Error,but when I want to delete the allocated Array for The `overflowIF` the Program is getting crashed & display not Responding Message,I'm doing deletion like This:

```
emxDestroyArray_real_T(overflowIF)
```

Also have the Same problem for overflowIFTemp deletion

can anyone Tell me what's the Problem with this Code!?

Thank you All guys :)

Comment: Why are you editing generated c++ code? Why not editing Matlab code first and see, what happens in generated code? And then just link to an existing generated library?

Comment: You are using NULL pointer when creating them. If you are assigning these pointers data created from some where else you should not need to use emxCreateWrapper_real_T.